# Creating a JSON from xml with date and time logic templates

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to create a JSON from a XML which has messages and each message has its date/time.

Below is the XML

```
  <message>
     <messageText heading="Temporary Maintenance Message 1">test message1</messageText>

     <displayScheduleContainer>
        <startDate>22/05/2019</startDate>
        <startTimeHrs>12</startTimeHrs>
        <startTimeMins>45</startTimeMins>
        <noEndDate>true</noEndDate>
     </displayScheduleContainer>
  </message>

   <message>
     <messageText heading="Temporary Maintenance Message 1">test message2</messageText>

     <displayScheduleContainer>
        <startDate>22/06/2019</startDate>
        <startTimeHrs>12</startTimeHrs>
        <startTimeMins>45</startTimeMins>
        <noEndDate>true</noEndDate>
     </displayScheduleContainer>
  </message>
```

The logic inside XSLT reads the date and time to activate the message

```
   <xsl:for-each select="xalan:nodeset($messageData)/activeMessage/message">

    <xsl:variable name="variableN">
        <xsl:call-template name="jsonMsg" />
    </xsl:variable>


    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$variableN = 'true'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="messageText/text()" />
            <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>

    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template name="jsonMsg">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="displayScheduleContainer/noEndDate = 'true'">
            <xsl:variable name="messageInDateTime">
                <xsl:call-template name="noEndDateTemplate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="startDateTime"
                        select="concat(displayScheduleContainer/startDate, ' ', displayScheduleContainer/startTimeHrs, ':', displayScheduleContainer/startTimeMins)" />

                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$messageInDateTime" />
        </xsl:when>

    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="noEndDateTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="startDateTime" />

    <xsl:variable name="sdf"
        select="java:text.SimpleDateFormat.new('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm')" />
    <xsl:variable name="currentDateTime" select="java:util.Date.new()" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when
            test="java:compareTo(java:parse($sdf, $startDateTime), $currentDateTime) &lt; 0">
            <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>


</xsl:template>
```

The problem i'm facing here is if the last value is false, I end up getting the comma at the end. As i'm checking for the last position and adding the comma. Due to this the whole JSON is broken. In this case it adds the comma because i'm displaying the text only if it is true.

```
 "message": ["test message1", ]
```

I'm using XSLT 1.0

Comment: Select only messages that satisfy the condition. Can't show you how because you did not post a [mcve]. And the snippet shown makes no sense, since the value of variable will be the same for all messages.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I've added a more detailed version to the original question. Please let me know if that helps to explain the issue

Comment: Just barely. You're supposed to post code (XML + XSLT) that can be run without modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `xsl:choose`, append a *predicate* to your `select` expression. Here's a simplified example:

**XML**

```
<messages>
    <message>
        <messageText>test message1</messageText>
        <displayScheduleContainer>
            <noEndDate>true</noEndDate>
        </displayScheduleContainer>
    </message>
    <message>
        <messageText>test message2</messageText>
        <displayScheduleContainer>
            <noEndDate>true</noEndDate>
        </displayScheduleContainer>
    </message>
    <message>
        <messageText>test message3</messageText>
        <displayScheduleContainer>
            <noEndDate>false</noEndDate>
        </displayScheduleContainer>
    </message>
</messages>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/messages">
    <xsl:for-each select="message[displayScheduleContainer/noEndDate = 'true']">
        <xsl:value-of select="messageText" />
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
"test message1,test message2"
```

---

### Added:

If the test is too complex to fit in a predicate, do the transformation in two passes. Here, again, a simplified example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/messages">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="eligible-messages">
        <xsl:for-each select="message">
            <xsl:if test="displayScheduleContainer/noEndDate = 'true'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($eligible-messages)/message">
        <xsl:value-of select="messageText" />
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Replace the `test` in:

```
<xsl:if test="displayScheduleContainer/noEndDate = 'true'">
```

with the test/s you want to perform.

Comment: The issue here is with the true or false value returned from the template after calculating the timing logic that decides if the message has to be shown or not.
Even if the `<xsl:for-each select="message[displayScheduleContainer/noEndDate = 'true']"> '` there is another template that is called and decides if the message has to displayed or not

Comment: I am afraid I cannot comment further without an explanation of the logic that needs to be applied. In general, if you cannot use a predicate, you would use a variable to  store only the eligible messages, then run a `xsl:for-each` on that. It seems you already have such variable, so you could do this elimination when you populate it (a step not shown in your question).

Comment: The logic is inside `noEndDateTemplate` which I have also pasted in the initial question. The template compares the given date and time in XML with the server and returns true or false. I'm already storing the values returned in a variable `"$variableN = 'true'"`, but  if the last value is false, the previous value is not knowing it.

Comment: Also is it possible to capture all the values with "true" in a single array and then process a `xsl:for-each` on it?

Comment: Yes, see the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Still no luck .I've added my modified code to the original post that can be used without any modifications to see the output.
Due the fact that the output is 
`truefalse` the coomma issue is still there as the last position is still satisfied and does not know that the value is false :(

Comment: Since you have posted this as a new question, I will not continue here. I suggest you revert your question here to the original and close it.

Comment: Thanks for your time on this one. I will try out the other solution by you and continue on the other post.