# Get rid off comma for the last element in the for each loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to create a JSON from a XML which has messages and each message has its date/time.

XML

```
  <messages>
    <message>
        <messageText>test message1</messageText>
        <displayScheduleContainer>
<startDate>22/05/2019</startDate>
<startTimeHrs>12</startTimeHrs>
<startTimeMins>45</startTimeMins>
            <noEndDate>true</noEndDate>
        </displayScheduleContainer>
    </message>
    <message>
        <messageText>test message2</messageText>
        <displayScheduleContainer>
<startDate>22/06/2019</startDate>
<startTimeHrs>12</startTimeHrs>
<startTimeMins>45</startTimeMins>
            <noEndDate>true</noEndDate>
        </displayScheduleContainer>
    </message>
    <message>
        <messageText>test message3</messageText>
        <displayScheduleContainer>
<startDate>22/06/2019</startDate>
<startTimeHrs>12</startTimeHrs>
<startTimeMins>45</startTimeMins>
            <noEndDate>false</noEndDate>
        </displayScheduleContainer>
    </message>
</messages>
```

The logic inside XSLT reads the date and time to activate the message

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:java="java"  xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/messages">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="eligible-messages">
        <xsl:for-each select="message">

            <xsl:if test="displayScheduleContainer/noEndDate = 'true'">
              <xsl:variable name="messageInDateTime">
        <xsl:call-template name="noEndDateTemplate">
           <xsl:with-param name="startDateTime" select="concat(displayScheduleContainer/startDate, ' ', displayScheduleContainer/startTimeHrs, ':', displayScheduleContainer/startTimeMins)" />
         </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="$messageInDateTime = 'true'" >
                    <xsl:copy-of select="messageText/text()" />
                    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>

                 </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
<xsl:value-of select="$eligible-messages" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="noEndDateTemplate">
        <xsl:param name="startDateTime" />
        <xsl:variable name="sdf" select="java:text.SimpleDateFormat.new('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm')" />
        <xsl:variable name="currentDateTime" select="java:util.Date.new()" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="java:compareTo(java:parse($sdf, $startDateTime), $currentDateTime) &lt; 0">
                <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>


    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem i'm facing here is if the last value is false, I end up getting the comma at the end. As i'm checking for the last position and adding the comma. Due to this the whole JSON is broken. In this case it adds the comma because i'm displaying the text only if it is true.

Output received

```
test message1,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not implementing correctly the answer you have received on your p[revious question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56282353/creating-a-json-from-xml-with-date-and-time-logic-templates). I am afraid I cannot verify your Java code, but I believe I am getting the correct result using:

**XSLT 1.0 (+EXSLT +Java)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:java="java"  
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/messages">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="eligible-messages">
        <xsl:for-each select="message[displayScheduleContainer/noEndDate = 'true']">
            <xsl:variable name="messageInDateTime">
                <xsl:call-template name="noEndDateTemplate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="startDateTime" select="concat(displayScheduleContainer/startDate, ' ', displayScheduleContainer/startTimeHrs, ':', displayScheduleContainer/startTimeMins)" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$messageInDateTime = 'true'" >
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($eligible-messages)/message">
        <xsl:value-of select="messageText" />
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="noEndDateTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="startDateTime" />
    <xsl:variable name="sdf" select="java:text.SimpleDateFormat.new('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm')" />
    <xsl:variable name="currentDateTime" select="java:util.Date.new()" />
    <xsl:value-of select="java:compareTo(java:parse($sdf, $startDateTime), $currentDateTime) &lt; 0"/>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```